# Zeebus Puzzle #8

Tags: word, rebus, literature

Don't be spook'ed by the math signs,
For they're the key to find the line...

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's this, but is it

> The Raven?

First

> de- for less which also sounds like the

Second:

> the second part might mean ray ven which is raven.

Tag:

> Since it is literature, I think it might be The Raven by Edgar Allan Poe.

SteveV has suggested that it might include

> Quote which might be Quoth (the Raven) or maybe nevermore due to the nature of the inequality

Comment: Nice, because that’s r13(enl-ira)

Comment: and maybe rot13(dhbgrf qr enl-ira vf dhbgu gur enira)

Comment: @SteveV Hm... maybe :)

Comment: Forgot to tell @El-Guest I liked his r13(enl-ira)!  But I do have another idea:  rot13(lbh pna nqq "arirezber" orpnhfr k vf nyjnlf yrff guna 0)

Comment: OOOH @SteveV well done! I quite like that!!

Comment: Due to the literature tag, I think it is the raven, but I'll add that to your suggestions

Comment: You have all the pieces, and the right train of though, in your submitted answer so I'll give it to you. Intended answer is the actual quote from the poem: "Dhbgu gur enira, arirezber." Nice work and welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: Thanks! ... I didn't know that was a famous quote... Oops... it said line

Comment: 1 1/2 months later: In a Dictionary Challenge (with teams; class was participating), my teacher put up _ _ _ _ _ the Raven, 'Nevermore' and then I remember this puzzle, which is the only way I knew the quote. I voted up now...